# sql query on gridview.kindly suggest of using date in when query

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT 
  MAX(CASE WHEN SDATE='1-JAN-14' THEN ITEM_NO ELSE 0 END) AS "1/1/2014", 
  MAX(CASE WHEN SDATE='2-JAN-14' THEN ITEM_NO ELSE 0 END) AS "2/1/2014", 
  PRICE 
FROM SAMP 
GROUP BY PRICE
```

Hi i tried this but am getting syntax error (missing operator). Can some one help me

Comment: I am using access database

Comment: Try using the [switch](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx) statement as CASE isn't understood by Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CASE` doesn't work with MS-ACCESS, Try this

```
SELECT 
  MAX(SWITCH(SDATE='1-JAN-14' ,ITEM_NO ,SDATE!='1-JAN-14',0)) AS "1/1/2014", 
  MAX(SWITCH(SDATE='2-JAN-14' ,ITEM_NO ,SDATE!='2-JAN-14',0)) AS "2/1/2014", 
  PRICE 
FROM SAMP 
GROUP BY PRICE
```

OR Simply

```
SELECT 
  MAX(SWITCH(SDATE='1-JAN-14' ,ITEM_NO )) AS "1/1/2014", 
  MAX(SWITCH(SDATE='2-JAN-14' ,ITEM_NO )) AS "2/1/2014", 
  PRICE 
FROM SAMP 
GROUP BY PRICE
```

Comment: @user3202126 try the edited, I was posting for MySQL previously!

Comment: HI,I think it will work,but there is "Data type mismatch" error.I do not know where it is going wrong

Comment: What is the datatype of ITEM_NO ?

Comment: SDATE is date? then you may have to input as date.. `SDATE=#1-JAN-14#`

Comment: Hi I have one more issue.From calender I will select date,but when I select date there it should automatically show previous two days data residing in datacase

Comment: is it different from your question you posted?

Comment: I am new to this site.may i know how to accept it as answered

Comment: There will be a tick mark, in top left of this answer.. below "0", you have to click on that invisible tick mark.

Comment: Hii I want to add this date function in join query but am facing error. Can you please suggest something from below queries

Comment: Hii I want to add this date function in join query but am facing error. Can you please suggest something from below queries   SELECT Sample_new.matno, Sample_new.rawpkgno, Sample_new.material, invorder.strno, invorder.transno, invorder.ordunits, invorder.ordcases, invorder.pcases, invorder.punits, invorder.deldate FROM (Sample_new LEFT JOIN invorder ON Sample_new.matno = invorder.matno) WHERE (invorder.deldate = ?) AND (invorder.strno = ?) OR 
([invorder.deldate] IS NULL) when i merge following code with this there is issue with groupby